# Query Cassandra and consume Kafka in order

Tags: cassandra, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark and not sure how this can be achieved.
Any idea on how to query Cassandra and consumer Kafka stream from same spark job. Basically,

1. I am trying to query cassandra and get some information when the job starts.
2. Then, go ahead and consume Kafka. Using the information that I got from cassandra to transform the data from kafka.
   So, How can I ensure the order of these two events.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with spark-cassandra-connector. That is you combine the code that connect and query cassandra with the code that send data to kafka.
You can find the java implement of for reading and writing into cassandra [here](https://gist.github.com/jacek-lewandowski/278bfc936ca990bee35a). To send your data to kafka, please take a look on at the method sendToKafka of [this code](https://github.com/streamlyio/streamly-spark-examples/blob/master/streamly-mqtt-kafka/src/main/java/io/streamly/examples/StreamlyMqttKafka.java).

Comment: Thanks, but I am still not sure how to ensure that things happen in that order. Basically, data information on how data is transformed comes from cassandra. So I need to somehow enforce that dependency so that the spark job applies transformation only after it has read data form cassandra.

Comment: I'm not very show I understand the issue you are facing now. Because when I look at the method showResults on the code https://gist.github.com/jacek-lewandowski/278bfc936ca990bee35a, I think you can just replace the System.out.println(result); with a call to the method sendToKafka of this code https://github.com/streamlyio/streamly-spark-examples/blob/master/streamly-mqtt-kafka/src/main/java/io/streamly/examples/StreamlyMqttKafka.java